# Как удалить mysqld из автозагрузки в фоновые процессы Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, autoload

Подскажите пожалуйста как "выпилить" автозапуск mysqld в фоновые процессы ("демоны") Ubuntu 16.04 ?

я попробовал комментировать в файле /etc/init.d/mysql блок кода 'start', но ничего не изменилось.

```
case "${1:-''}" in
  'start')
    sanity_checks;
    # Start daemon
    log_daemon_msg "Starting MySQL database server" "mysqld"
    if mysqld_status check_alive nowarn; then
       log_progress_msg "already running"
       log_end_msg 0
    else
...
```

Я хотел бы вручную запускать службу mysql через консоль.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Подскажите пожалуйста как "выпилить" автозапуск mysqld в фоновые процессы ("демоны") Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Как и во всех основанных на `systemd` дистрибутивах:

```
systemctl disable mysql
```

От root'а, само собой.